# YAML: dump_all saves an empty file

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I am trying to open a yaml file, update a value and save it. I have followed many examples already provided on stackoverflow, but it still doesn't work.

My code:
import yaml

```
def update(x:int):
    with open("fileWithValues.yaml", "r") as yaml_file:
        try:
            docs=yaml.load_all(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
            for doc in docs:
                for key, value in doc.items():
                    if value == "city":
                        doc["year"]["value"] = x
                        break

            with open("fileWithValues.yaml", 'w') as yaml_file:
                yaml.dump_all(docs, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
```

As said, to create the code, I have followed several examples from stackoverflow. But still, after executing the code it seems that it is opening the file to write in it but it leaves it empty. To summarize, the first part where I read the file works. The part where it is supposed to dump all the documents doesn't. It is not throwing any exception or error message. It just saves an empty file.

Additional info: the file I am reading contains two documents. And the value I update is in the second one.

Update: example file used to get the first data

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aa
  labels:
    app: aa
    service: aa
spec:
  selector:
    app: aa
  ports:
  - name: tcp-send
    port: 9000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: capture-v1
  labels:
    app: aa
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: aa
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aa
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aa
        image: someimage:0.3
        ports:
          - name: tcp-send
            containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: bb-aa
          mountPath: /etc/localtime
      volumes:
        - name: bb-aa
          hostPath:
            path: /path/
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: serve3
...
```

Target parameter to be changed is: 2nd document, spec, **replicas**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `with` statements are nested, so you're opening the file in write mode while it is already open in read mode. Separate them like so:

```py
def update(x:int):
    try:
        with open("fileWithValues.yaml", "r") as yaml_file:
            docs = list(yaml.load_all(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader))
        for doc in docs:
            for key, value in doc.items():
                if value == "city":
                    doc["year"]["value"] = x
                    break

        with open("fileWithValues.yaml", 'w') as yaml_file:
            yaml.dump_all(docs, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Comment: hm, it makes sense what you are proposing, but it leads to `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: @WestCoast I see, apparently the file is loaded lazily. I've updated my answer, please try with the slightly different indentation

Comment: well the error is gone, but it is still saving an empty file... quite confusing, it should be working :(

Comment: I have updated my question with an example file. Maybe that helps

Comment: @WestCoast you can eagerly load all documents by calling `list()` on the generator, see my updated answer. However, your example data isn't actually updated since the condition is never true.